# E: Archives directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial is missing. - Acquire (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: command-line, apt, python

I am trying to install a python version on linux. But I am getting the following error:

```
E: Archives directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial is missing.
Acquire (2: No such file or directory)
```

Edit:

```
$ ls -l /var/cache/apt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       14  july 18 17:20 archives -> /new/cache/dir
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55665645  july 18 17:55 pkgcache.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 55624587  july 18 17:55 srcpkgcache.bin
```

How can I solve this?? Thank you!